# Running a hadoop streaming and mapreduce job: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads() : subprocess failed with code 127

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run this on my own Hadoop cluser. I ran the job using the following command.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-3.1.0.jar -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -file mapper.py -file reducer.py -input wiki.xml -output output4
```

But getting the following error!

```
2018-10-20 16:05:50,021 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [mapper.py, reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-unjar707072106784045009/] [] /tmp/streamjob4878270244056389381.jar tmpDir=null
2018-10-20 16:05:51,845 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
2018-10-20 16:05:52,512 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
2018-10-20 16:05:53,503 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/anubhav/.staging/job_1540029454250_0014
2018-10-20 16:05:56,044 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2018-10-20 16:05:56,431 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
2018-10-20 16:05:56,496 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-10-20 16:05:56,686 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1540029454250_0014
2018-10-20 16:05:56,688 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2018-10-20 16:05:57,125 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-10-20 16:05:57,125 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-10-20 16:05:57,550 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1540029454250_0014
2018-10-20 16:05:57,627 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://anubhav-Inspiron-3542:8088/proxy/application_1540029454250_0014/
2018-10-20 16:05:57,629 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1540029454250_0014
2018-10-20 16:06:07,874 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1540029454250_0014 running in uber mode : false
2018-10-20 16:06:07,890 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-10-20 16:06:16,052 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:16,079 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:26,193 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:27,203 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:37,310 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:37,314 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1540029454250_0014_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2018-10-20 16:06:49,429 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2018-10-20 16:06:51,458 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1540029454250_0014 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1540029454250_0014_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

2018-10-20 16:06:51,571 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 14
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=105898
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=52949
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=52949
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=162659328
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
2018-10-20 16:06:51,571 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

I have also added
                `#! /usr/bin/python`
at the beginning of my both files mapper.py and reducer.py

Answer (score 2):

If you use python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this problem by changing

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running a python 3 command (string formatting for example) in python 2